# I want to download image from url and save it to device's internal memory and play after successfully saved?

Tags: android

This is my code. When i run this code showing me error. Help me with that i already wasted lots of time on this task.

```
public class AndroidDownloadFileByProgressBarActivity extends Activity {

    // button to show progress dialog
    Button btnShowProgress;
    MediaController mediaController ;
    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    VideoView videoView;
    // Progress dialog type (0 - for Horizontal progress bar)
    public static final int progress_bar_type = 0; 

    // File url to download
    private static String file_url = "http://192.168.1.107/MSEManagement/static/uploads/productIntroduction/4/4.mp4";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // show progress bar button
        btnShowProgress = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnProgressBar);
        // Image view to show image after downloading
        //videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.my_image);
        /**
         * Show Progress bar click event
         * */
        btnShowProgress.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // starting new Async Task
                new DownloadFileFromURL().execute(file_url);
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Showing Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
        case progress_bar_type:
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Downloading file. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setMax(100);
            pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
            return pDialog;
        default:
            return null;
        }
    }

    class DownloadFileFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            showDialog(progress_bar_type);
        }

        /**
         * Downloading file in background thread
         * */
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
            int count;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);
                URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
                conection.connect();
                // getting file length
                int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();

                // input stream to read file - with 8k buffer
                InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);

                // Output stream to write file
                OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/4.mp4");

                byte data[] = new byte[1024];

                long total = 0;

                while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                    total += count;
                    // publishing the progress....
                    // After this onProgressUpdate will be called
                    publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));

                    // writing data to file
                    output.write(data, 0, count);
                }


                output.flush();

                // closing streams
                output.close();
                input.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            }

            return null;
        }


        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
            // setting progress percentage
            pDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
       }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after the file was downloaded
            dismissDialog(progress_bar_type);

            // Displaying downloaded image into image view
            // Reading image path from sdcard
            videoView =(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView);

            mediaController= new MediaController(AndroidDownloadFileByProgressBarActivity.this);
            mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);

            Uri uri=Uri.parse("/sdcard/4.mp4");
            videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
            videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
            videoView.requestFocus();
            videoView.start();
          }

    }
```

When i run my code on my phone its running but not working android emulators. What should i do now i am stuck in these things.

D/VideoView: Error: 1,0

E/Error:: /sdcard/4.mp4 (Permission denied)

W/MediaPlayer: Couldn't open /sdcard/4.mp4: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: /sdcard/4.mp4

W/VideoView: Unable to open content: /sdcard/4.mp4

```
         java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sdcard/4.mp4 (Permission denied)
```

Comment: post the log here

Comment: "this code showing me error". And where's the error?

Comment: you should ask run time read and write storage permissions for android version>=marshmellow

Comment: Try to get the file from getExternalStorageFile and add the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE to manifest, maybe it is a dangerous permission that you need to ask for runtime permission

Answer (score 0):

If your app run correctly on your phone and does not work on emulator,
these can be happen

- Your Manifest file should include permissions like a

  ```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  ```
- Maybe your phone SDK Version and emulator have different sdk try it same sdk version emulator with you phone.